# ownCloud server: DBA_DEFAULT PHP error

Tags: php, database, mariadb, owncloud, synology

I've got an issue running my ownCloud instance on a Synology NAS. I get to following log error:

> PHP Startup: No such handler: DBA_DEFAULT at Unknown#0

... which should be about the connection to the database.
It is very confusing, because the database can be called by ownCloud, all connected clients work, the web interface works and so on... Only this message remains.

My configuration details:

- Synology DS216j with DSM 6.0.2-8451 Update 7
- PHP 5.6.28
- MariaDB 5.5.53
- ownCloud 9.1.3

I can find absolutely no information about that error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been seeing this message on my Synology NAS recently and this is what I've found.  My NAS has multiple Php installations, and I think this error is coming from the default installation.

```
root@synology:~# /bin/php --ri dba
Extension 'dba' not present.
```

but using my alternate php

```
root@synology:~# /usr/local/bin/php56 --ri dba

dba

DBA support => enabled
Supported handlers => gdbm cdb cdb_make db4 inifile flatfile 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
dba.default_handler => flatfile => flatfile
```

So one solution is to ensure that your application is invoking the correct Php version.  For this you can manage the HTTP server and PHP version from the Synology **Web Station**.

Alternately I noticed that this message is `E_WARNING` level only and can be ignored (unless you need Berkley Database). I added this code to my application

```
function shutdownHandler()
{
    try {
        $error = error_get_last();
        if ( $error !== NULL && $error["type"] == E_ERROR) {
            $backtrace = "(E_ERROR) " . $error["message"];

            $trace = debug_backtrace();
            foreach($trace as $item) {
                $backtrace .= "\n\t" . (isset($item['file']) ? $item['file'] : '<unknown file>')
                    . ' ' . (isset($item['line']) ? $item['line'] : '<unknown line>')
                    . ' calling ' . (isset($item['function']) ? $item['function'] : '<unknown function>') . '()';
            }

            \Logger::LogError( $backtrace, $error["file"], $error["line"]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        print get_class($e)." thrown within the shutdown handler. Message: ".$e->getMessage()." on line ".$e->getLine();
    }
}

# Registering shutdown function
register_shutdown_function('shutdownHandler');
```

I'm guessing **ownCloud** has a similar function, but it is probably logging all error messages, which is why you are seeing this message.

Comment: Thank you for this hint! I switched my PHP versions before in the Web Station, but the message did not go away. Finally I saw that none of them had a dba handler assigned (i.e.: DBA_DEFAULT). But in the Web Station under "PHP Settings" -> Select the PHP version you use -> "Advanced Settings" (? I use the german version) -> "Advanced" I found the "dba.handler_default" entry and inserted "flatfile" instead of "DBA_DEFAULT". The error did not occur since 24h... I don't want to edit my post and add this as a solution, because I don't know how accurate it is. :-/

Answer (score 1):

This happend on my DS114 with DSM 6.0.2-8451 Update 7 also, after the upgrade of Apache 2.2 on 6 January 2017. Before the upgrade all worked fine.

I have changed /volume1/@appstore/Apache2.2/usr/local/etc/apache22/conf/extra/mod_xsendfile.conf

from

XSendFilePath /var/services/web /var/services/homes

to

XSendFilePath /volume1/owncloud

and now it works again